# Backbone fetch hitting the wrong url

Tags: backbone.js, model, fetch

I'm have the following backbone model

```
define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
    function ($, _, Backbone) {
        var file_upload = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/customForms'

    });

    return file_upload;
}
```

I have a view loaded at

localhost:38559/app/forms.html

which tries to do a post with the following code

```
var fd = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
var file = new file_upload();
file.fetch({data: $.param({fileToUpload: fd}), 
    type: 'POST', 
    success: function(d){
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

but this seems to just do a get request to forms.html passing fd as a param. I've also tried overriding the sync method in file_upload

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {
    var self = this;
    options = _(options).clone();

    var error = options.error;
    options.error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
        if (error)
            error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    };

    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (success && data) {
            alert("Success uploading form.");
            success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
        else
            alert("Error uploading form. Please try entering again.");
        };

        var params = {
            type: 'POST'
        };
        $.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
    }
}
```

I'm doing posts in other parts of the app with similar code so can't figure out why with this code the fetch does a get request to the page it's called on rather than a post to the url specified in the model. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Derm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh - finally found the issue coming back to this. The file upload was been done on a button click event. I needed to call preventdefault to force the use of the models url rather than the pages url. Annoying issue - dunno how I missed it! Code now is

```
uploadForm: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    var fd = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    var file = new file_upload();
    file.fetch({data: $.param({fileToUpload: fd}), 
        type: 'POST', 
        success: function(d){
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
},
```